How to draw a 3D mask on the face in android media pipe
[![ After I get 468 points ( x, y ,z) from how can I draw a mask (use .obj file)on my face, please give me some tutorial make a mask in face by android java or kotlin.you have example please share with me.......
](https://i.sstatic.net/mLF17vjD.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/mLF17vjD.png)


Hi, Have you got any logic. I am also trying to use the result by mediapipe and show 3d model in Web. But the coordinates by mediapipe are in screen space and 3d model uses world space units. I could not able to map those
